# Gets all simple products that belong to a "enabled" configurable product

Tags: product, configurable-product, performance, product-collection

I used following code:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_product_collection')
        ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
        ->setFlag('product_children', true);
```

But how can only select simple products that belongs to an enabled configurable product (status = 'enabled'). Above code don't care about parent product's status. I need most efficient way to do it as I have thousands of products in my store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please using the follow code:

```
$configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->collection();
$simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
```

This will give you all simple product array belong to configurable product. For enable make sure to

> addAttributeToSelect

enalble product or status having yes. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        echo $simple_product->getSku() . " - " . $simple_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . "<br>";
    }
endif;
```

**second code
Use with set product filter**

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_product_collection')
            ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
            ->setFlag('product_children', true)     
            ->setProductFilter($this->getProduct($_product))      
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```